# Can somebody explain the -R option for userdel command?

Tags: linux

Can somebody explain the `-R` option for `userdel` command? I couldn't understand its description in the man page. I know what the `chroot` command is but I can't understand how is it related to `userdel`.

Answer (score 2):

Some `userdel` versions have this option:

```
 -R, --root CHROOT_DIR
     Apply changes in the CHROOT_DIR directory and use the
     configuration files from the CHROOT_DIR directory.
```

In other words, instead of editing `/etc/passwd` and friends,
you're editing `CHROOT_DIR/etc/passwd`.

For example, you might boot a live CD, mount the hard drive as `/mnt`,
and then use `-R /mnt` to edit its users.

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102152/17660)

Comment: And some userdel versions appear to support -R even when it's not mentioned in the man page. Example, Debian 10.